# How to use AMP for email to track open click?

Tags: html-email, tracking, amp-email

I was looking to get [open/click](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/email-spec/amp-email-format/#tracking-email-opens-and-interaction) tacking using [AMP for Emails](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/integrate/add-email/?format=email)
but yet to find any conclusive document to get any idea that how I can get tracking using AMP for emails.

Below is the sample code give by AMP but there is no tracking link of something given.

```
<!--
## Introduction

This sample demonstrates how to display a feed of data, allowing the user to go through
a large number of items in an email without having to scroll.

The sample uses a combination of [`amp-list`](/documentation/components/amp-list),
to fetch the initial items from the server and [`amp-form`](/documentation/components/amp-form),
to "refresh" a single item, by making a new server request.
-->

<!-- -->
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email lang="en" data-css-strict>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
  <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>

  <!--
    ## Styles

    We use CSS to hide the initially fetched item after the form is first submitted.

    We also define a layout that allows us to have fixed card sizes, to ensure form submissions don't result in content jumps.
  -->
  <style amp-custom>
    .amp-form-submit-success .initial-content,
    .amp-form-submitting .initial-content,
    .amp-form-submit-error .initial-content {
      display: none;
    }

    .card {
      width: 160px;
      height: 120px;
      margin: 10px;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
    }

    .card .next-button {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!--
    ## Single item template

    Define a template for a single item inside a card and give it an `id`. This template is used by `amp-form` for displaying new items.

    In this case, we use a single `amp-img`.
  -->
  <template id="item-template" type="amp-mustache">
    <amp-img src="{{items.imageUrl}}" layout="fixed" width="160" height="90"></amp-img>
  </template>

  <!--
    ## Initial list of items

    We define a template for the initial items and their layout and give it an `id`, allowing us to use it subsequently in an amp-list. This template is used by `amp-list` for fetching the initial up-to-date contents from the server.

    It contains in itself an `amp-form` for each item which references the template defined above referred by its `id`. By using a different template for the `amp-form`, we're able to "refresh" a part of the content, namely the image in this case.

    Note: This template contains the same markup (in this case, a single `amp-img`) as used in the template above to render the initial items. This is wrapped inside `<div class="initial-content">` which becomes hidden the first time the user submits the form.
  -->
  <template id="list-template" type="amp-mustache">
    <form class="card" method="post" action-xhr="https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/api/photo-stream?single&width=160&height=90">
      <div class="initial-content">
        <amp-img src="{{imageUrl}}" layout="fixed" width="160" height="90"></amp-img>
      </div>

      <div submit-success template="item-template"></div>

      <input class="next-button" type="submit" value="Next">
    </form>
  </template>

  <!--
    We use `amp-list` to render the initial items from the server using the template defined above referred by its `id`.

    The height matches the combined height of our cards and their margins. The initial server response defines the number of cards to be displayed (in this case four).
  -->
  <amp-list template="list-template" src="https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/api/photo-stream?width=160&height=90&items=4" layout="fixed" width="360" height="280">
  </amp-list>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone give a idea to implement tracking on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says "AMPHTML allows tracking email opens with pixel tracking techniques, same as regular HTML emails."

There is therefore no specific AMP way of doing it--it's just normal.

So, normally the ESP handles open tracking, and perhaps click tracking too, by rewriting the URLs. Alternatively, you can add for example UTM links if you use Google Analytics on the site the links are going to.

Comment: Actually I am talking about "AMPForEMAIL". Where I they donot provide normal tracking. so we have to do something from our side so that we can check , user who get the email , what he saw (which image if you use multiple in carousel) etc.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/add_advanced/tracking_data/?format=websites

Comment: No this is google analytics, which can we seen in google platform, I want something custom which I can see or save in my own platform, like in email marketing people use tiny image to track open, click etc.

Comment: The documentation about tracking mentioned in this answer is for AMP for Email. As @Nathan mentioned above, there's nothing special about the use of tracking pixels in AMP emails except that you would use `amp-img` instead of `img`. You could also use CSS `background-image` which works the same way as static emails.

Comment: You said you wanted to track opens as well as clicks. You can use amp-analytics or amp-pixel - both parts are on that link. Here's the direct link for the 'tiny image' open tracking: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-pixel/?format=websites

Comment: amp-analytics don't work for amp for emails, (mentioned in there website)
Important: this documentation is not applicable to your currently selected format "email!"
 that is why I was asking for alternative.

Comment: There's also nothing special about tracking clicks in AMP for Email. You would use the same technique that you use in static HTML emails: wrapping the original URL with a URL redirector which is hosted by a service that does the tracking for you.  ESPs normally support this out of the box. For example, here's how Mailchimp does it: https://mailchimp.com/help/enable-and-view-click-tracking.